# View rest/page copycat

Tags: views, 8

In view, when I set the settings to field field1 in *Page*, the same settings apply to field1 in *Rest export*. How do I get rid of it?

I see that everything is copied. I deleted the field from *Rest export*, and it disappears also in *Page*.

Comment: When adding a field, filter, etc... there should be a drop down to change from inheriting to overriding. Once that is done, all fields (if you added a field), filters (if you added a filter), etc... will be in overidden state for that views display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

When you click on `add / remove / edit` a `field / filter / sort / contextual filter` etc.. at the very top, you need to change the **For** `All displays` to `This page (override)` so it does not affect all the other views. You only need to do this for the first time, it will remember your setting.

**Note:** `field / filter / sort / contextual filter` etc... each have individual settings.